# Is there a way to see all web connections your mac has made? ip and ports?

Tags: macos, mac, internet, iphone, audio-streaming

I'm trying to find out what the exact connection my mac is connected to when i stream radio from

http://www.talksport.co.uk/radio/listen-live

The reason I wanted to find out the exact connection is do that I can use it on my iphone app to listen to the station.

http://202.6.74.107:8060/triplej.mp3

Works to connect to Tripple J station. So that i guess is what I want to discover. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
netstat -anp tcp
```

lists all currently running tcp connections.

Answer (score 1):

[tcpdump](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3994?viewlocale=en_US)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has mentioned it, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) is the One True Way to reverse engineer network protocols.

Answer (score 0):

it's also likely that the well-known utility LITTLE SNITCH could help you.

Just google it up and buy a copy.